# how to make a seemingly endless backdrop in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, terrain, skybox

Potential solution at the bottom.

I have a rocket which flies straight up, as it gets higher you can see the edge of the terrain. I want the rocket to eventually leave the atmosphere and then the landscape to disappear from view as the player would be so high up.

How do i make it appear that the landscape is endless?

image pre launch:
[image: Pre Launch]

image post launch:

[image: Post Launch]

My solution to anyone who has the same type of question

firstly i made a mountain range using the terrain, a 3x3 tiled one worked for me. I then used the lighting settings to add fog to the scene, to slightly obscure the mountains. Lastly i rotated the camera upward by -5 when the rokcet reached a certain position to further hide the blankness behind the mountains. images shown below:

pre-camera rotation
[image: pre rotation]

post-camera rotation
[image: post rotation]

Comment: Could you add some detail, diagrams, or examples to show the type/style of "endless" you are going for? There are various visual effects that could achieve an "endless" look, so it would help to have your desired style narrowed down a bit to advise you on a specific implementation.

Comment: I think what i'm going to do is to create several images facing the camera of mountains from ground level at different distances then have another image on top facing upwards that is the mountains from a birds eye view. If there is a better way to do that id like to hear it.

Comment: So aside from controlling the camera and placing objects in the scene, both of which you seem to be comfortable doing, what are you struggling with in achieving the desired effect? Perhaps in addition to placing terrain in the distance to give a sense of scale during takeoff, I would consider some system to spawn clouds/stars/asteroids and other atmospheric objects above the current position and then despawn them once they are far enough away. Zooming past these objects will give a sense of movement and scale.

Comment: Thank you, i've made a large set of mountains using the terrain tool in the background. 3x3 tiles. I'm going to put some fog on the horizon to cloud the view after the mountains. I'm also going to pivot the camera to face upward very slightly to hide it, when the rocket reaches a certain height. I'll edit my post with the after image and explain it for anyone else having a similar question